# Finding constants of an equation using equation the coefficients or convenient values method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the constants for the equation $$\frac{30x-17}{(6x-1)^2}=\frac{A}{6x-1}+\frac{B}{(6x-1)^2}$$

Multiplying by lowest common denominator yields $$30x-17=A(6x-1)+B$$

This can be written as $30x-17=6A\cdot x-A+B$, but I am unsure of where to go from there.

Comment: Hint substitute values for $x $. Try $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Now you have two equations and two unknowns. $$30 = 6A \\ -17 = B-A$$ Can you see how I got these?

Comment: Much appreciated!  I was getting there!

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{30x-17}{(6x-1)^2}=\frac{A}{6x-1}+\frac{B}{(6x-1)^2}$

$\implies 30x-17=A(6x-1)+B$

$\implies 30x-17=6Ax-A+B$

comparing both sides, we have

$6A=30~\&~-A+B=-17$

So from first equation we'll get $A=5$ putting $A=5$ in second equation we get $B=-12$.

Answer (score 0):

$$30x-17=A(6x-1)+B$$

$ x = \frac 16 \rightarrow  B = 5-17 = -12 $

$ x = 0 \rightarrow  -17 = -A  + B = -A -12$